# A set of continuous functions from $(X, τ_X )$ to $(\mathbb{R}, τ_E )$ satisfying some properties

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Let $(X,τ_X)$ be a compact topological space and let $F$ be a set of continuous functions from $(X, τ_X)$ to $(\mathbb{R}, τ_E)$ satisfying the following properties:

• for each $f \in F$ and each $x \in X$,we have that $f(x) \geq 0$,

•for each $f \in F$ there is some $x_f \in X$ with $f(x_f)=0$,

• F is stable under addition: if $f \in F, g \in F$, then also $f + g \in F$.

I would like to prove that there is some $x_0 \in X$ such that $f(x_0) = 0$ $\forall f \in F$. I tried combining the three properties and obtained the following :

Let $(f_i)_{i \in I}$ be a countable collection of functions in $F$. From the third property we know that $\sum_{i \in I} f_i \in F$.

Therefore from the second property we know that $\exists x_0$ such that $$\sum_{i \in I} f_i(x_0) = 0.$$
Using first property we deduce that $f_i(x_0) = 0$ $\forall i \in I$.

Then I also know that $(X,τ_X)$ is compact hence $\forall f \in F, f(X)$ is compact. But now i don't see how to go any further with that.

Any help would be very appreciated. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose for a contradiction there is no $x_0$ such that $f(x_0) = 0 \; \forall f \in F$ then we must have

$$\bigcap_{f \in F} f^{-1}(\{0\}) = \emptyset$$
$$\Longrightarrow \bigcup_{f \in F} X \setminus f^{-1}(\{0\}) = X$$
$X$ Compact $\Longrightarrow \exists f_1,...,f_n$ such that
$$\bigcup_{i=1}^{n} X \setminus f_{i}^{-1}(\{0\}) = X$$
then now you also have
$$\bigcap_{i=1}^{n} f_{i}^{-1}(\{0\}) = \emptyset$$

I'll let you conclude with the other properties.

Comment: It's basically the same argument but a little cleaner: family of closed sets of the form $f^{-1}(0)$ for $f\in F$ has finite intersection property, so their intersection is non-empty from compactness of $X$.